# docker start with "failed to retrieve runc version: fork/exec /usr/bin/runc: exec format error"

Tags: docker

I have to install docker in a environment without public network access, so I download the docker binary `docker-19.03.4.tgz` from here https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/

and when I start the `docker`, I got the "failed to retrieve runc version" error:

```
INFO[2019-11-04T12:42:25.008140185+08:00] Loading containers: done.
WARN[2019-11-04T12:42:25.013531207+08:00] failed to retrieve runc version: fork/exec /usr/bin/runc: exec format error
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error) from ask ubuntu, this error usually indicates running a binary on an incompatible machine.
You are probably trying to run in an incompatible version of the docker runtime with your machine.
You should compare the architecture of the machine you intend to run docker on with different releases docker offers, and choose the right one.